# Filter rows based on vector index instead of column name or index

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a very simple sample data frame df_test as:

```r
df_test <- data.frame("A" = 1:5)
```

I would like to select the row containing 5. I know I can achieve it by using the `filter()` command as:

```r
df_analysis <- df_test %>% 
  filter(A == 5)
```

However, I want to run a for loop (as the actual data set has many variables and is complex), thus instead of filtering columns manually one by one, I would like to run a for loop of columns that can pick one variable at a time and filter rows accordingly. For this example, I create a character vector `v` as `v = c("A")`.

Now to filter, instead of using the column name, when I try to use this vector index as:

```r
df_analysis <- df_test %>% 
  filter(v[1] == 5)
```

It produces 0 rows instead of 1.

How can I filter rows using vector index instead of column index or name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current form, your filter operation compares the literal string "A" (i.e., the contents of `v[1]`) to the numeric 5, which is of course always false and therefore can't return any valid rows. Instead, you'd need to pass the variable A (contained in df_test) as the first argument to `filter()`. You can do this by using `get()` like so:

```
df_analysis <- df_test %>% 
  filter(get(v[1]) == 5)
```

The other solution here using `purrr` is honestly much better, but I wanted to point out why your code didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

With the addition of `purrr`, you can do:

```
map(.x = v,
    ~ df_test %>%
     filter(across(all_of(.x)) == 5))

[[1]]
  A
1 5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
df_test[df_test[[v]] == 5, , drop = FALSE]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, by converting to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
df_test %>%
     filter(!! rlang::sym(v) == 5)
#  A
#1 5
```

---

Or with `.data`

```
df_test %>%
      filter(.data[[v]] == 5)
```